# How to save powerpoint with image compression activated

Tags: python, powerpoint

I'm trying to save space in my office folders. I have many, really many, presentation full of images. I managed to transform some of them into pdfs via python, that enlighten a bit the folders.

 But i need to keep for many other the pptx format. So I wonder if there is a way to re-save all the files (+1000) and activated image compression (and any other options that might save spaces without interfering too much with quality/readiness) ?

In clear someway to activate the following resolution options :

[image]

Comment: Did you already have a look at [pptx-downsizer 0.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/pptx-downsizer/)?

Comment: yes, the installation is not compatible with my environnement

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using powershell (solution given by a colleague (D.P.):

```
$path = "C:\Temp\ps_test"

$pptFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.ppt, *.pptx -recurse  # also searches subfolders
$objPowerpoint = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application

foreach($ppt in $pptFiles)
{
    $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($ppt.BaseName + ".pdf")
    $presentation = $objPowerpoint.Presentations.open($ppt.fullname, 3, 0, 0)  # keep the window hidden
    $presentation.Saved = $true
    "saving $filepath"
    $presentation.SaveAs($filepath, 32)  # 32 for pdf
    $presentation.close()
}
$objPowerpoint.Quit()
```